# Induction proof: monotonic inreasing

Tags: monotone-functions

Let c:$\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be a strictly monotonic inreasing function, proof by induction that $c \geq id_{\mathbb{N}}$ where id is the identity $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}:n \rightarrow n$.
I have to do it with induction, but c could be any strictly monotonic increasing function, so how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

We have that $c(1)$ is a natural number and thus $c(1)\geq 1$. So we have $c(n)\geq n$ for $n=1$.

Suppose now that for some natural number $k$ it is $c(k)\geq k$. Based on this assumption we will prove that $c(k+1)\geq k+1$. Since $c$ is a strictly increasing function with integer values, we have:

$c(k+1)>c(k)\Rightarrow c(k+1)\geq c(k)+1\Rightarrow c(k+1)\geq k+1$

Therefore the inductive proof is over. Hence $c(n)\geq n\ \forall n.$

*Note:* If you include $0$ in the set of natural numbers, the proof is similar.